# How to use rel=canonical, or javascript for 301 redirection

Tags: javascript, html

I have an old website which all the pages should redirect to the new pages. Because I was working so hard to make trafic on the old one I dont want to loose trafic and want to transfer all that on my new website. Any suggestion for 301 Redirecting for html pages or javascript?

Comment: Same domain, or different domain? Because if its the same domain, consider using the .htacces file

Comment: Different domain. Would you explain me how? I dont't see this file on server.

Answer (score 1):

Use htaccess for redirection instead of javascript (if you're on a *nix server that is). It should keep things very close as far as the ranking of your previous site. This would go into your .htaccess file at the root of your old site:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.newsite.com/
```

Comment: This is the best way and most solid way - everyone will be redirected, both real visitors and search engines. Avoid relying on javascript, it may lose you some visitors + I don't think search engines even care about javascript so it may lose you all rankings

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not on *nix. What should I do?

Comment: Actually it does not depend on whether you are on a *nix system or not but on whether you use Apache HTTPD server or not.

Comment: I'm so confused now. Would you kindly refer me an article or something that can help me or at least give me more I dea?

Comment: what web server and programming language are you using on the server? IIS on Windows? Also, who hosts the site?

Comment: Its IIS on Windows and Im using ASP for programing as well. The hosting company is http://infosaic.com/

Comment: Perhaps check this out? : http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/54313.aspx?p=2 - it sorta depends on if you have admin access to IIS.